# Tag [Bootstrap-modal] returns error or connection reset

Tags: bug, broken-link

Found this issue with following link

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&hideReview=on&minScore=0

When filter by tag: `Bootstrap-modal`, takes too much time to search and return's

1. Oops! something bad Happened (Chrome, Win-XP)

[image]

OR

2. The connection was reset (FireFox, Win 8.1)

[image]

Checked on 2 different laptops with different OS (XP and Wind8.1) using 2 different internet connections and 2 different browsers (Chrome & Firefox).

**Update**

Found same above issues with `fancybox-2` and `magnific-popup` tag(s)

Comment: Can't repro this, but it takes me to the homepage (aka /).

Comment: I think the `url` only accessible to SO logged-in users.

Comment: I *am* logged in.

Comment: No Idea why you can't see the correct page, But if I open the link in question, it takes me to the page http://shehary.com/stackimages/pagelink.jpg

Comment: So, I am using the new-new-new-nav, so yeah...

Comment: I can reproduce this on the old navigation.

Comment: Same problem for me on old nav. And judging by title, I though this is a burnination request :)